# what does the assignment mean interface Squel<S extends Select = Select>

Tags: typescript-typings

```
interface Squel<S extends Select = Select,
    U extends Update = Update,
    D extends Delete = Delete,
    I extends Insert = Insert,
    C extends Case = Case> {
```

I cannot understand the assignment after extends. Could someone explain it? I do not find in Typescript official document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are *generic parameter defaults*. They work similarly to default values for regular function parameters.

They allow you to not provide *type arguments* for *type parameters*.

```
let squel: Squel/*< no need to pass type arguments, yay! >*/
```

And if your type was like this:

```
interface Squel<S extends Select,
U extends Update,
D extends Delete,
I extends Insert,
C extends Case>
```

Then you would have to always pass type arguments:

```
let squel: Squel<Select, Update, Delete, Insert, Case>
                ^^^   this part is mandatory now   ^^^
```

P.S. The typescript handbook seems to not have information about this feature, but 2.3 release [does have it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html) (scroll to **Generic parameter defaults**)